# Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page. - wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i am getting this error message "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page".
when i go to my page http://localhost/wordpressstuff/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=editstuff?id=4 that is when i get the error but when i remove ?id=4 it removes the error i am trying to do a edit mysql table row but for some reason i am getting this in wordpresS
HERE IS MY CODE:

```
/** Step 2 (from text above). */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_edit_news_menu' );

/** Step 1. */
function my_edit_news_menu() {
    add_options_page( 'My Plugin Options', '', 'manage_options', 'editstuff', 'edit_news' );
}

/** Step 3. */
function edit_news() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'Well You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page. Embarassing is\'nt it' ) );
    }
...
```

hERE IS THE LINK THAT I CLICK TO GET TO THAT PAGE

```
<h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3> <h4 style="color: lightblue;"><a href="">Delete</a></h4> <h4 style="color: lightblue;"><a href="http://kollossus.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=editstuff?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Edit</a></h4>
```

Which is in a different page like the first one up there the first bit of code only exception is the stuff is different the url etc.

Thank You

Comment: I'm not sure is it help, but change 'options-general.php?page=editstuff?id=...' to 'options-general.php?page=editstuff&id=...'

Comment: add that as an answer (i will accept) it works thankyou @TomaszWinter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `options-general.php?page=editstuff?id=...` to `options-general.php?page=editstuff&id=...`

Comment: You should consider explaining the problem, i.e. the separator for GET variables is &, not ? It took me a couple minutes to see what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]: Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page

> Anytime I go to /wp-admin/ I get “Sorry, you are not allowed to access
> this page” The sites frontend works fine.
>
> I am no novice to solving WP problems but this one has me perplexed.
>
> So far I’ve: Reset .htaccess Disabled all plugins from folder & db
> Disabled custom themes from folder & db and have done tons of
> debugging
>
> I’ve been doing tests with the db and I can get it working normally if
> I replace the wp_options table with a fresh builds backup.
>
> I am now searching through the options table to find the issue. It
> might take me a while because my options table is 4000+ rows.
>
> Any ideas are welcome and greatly appreciated!

Solutions:

Ok after countless hours of examining wp_options tables in phpmyadmin I finally discovered the problem. Somehow the wp_user_role row got deleted. It can also happen if it is edited/changed by a plugin such as WooCommerce.

So to fix it I copied the following from a fresh install and inserted it into the wp_options table with phpmyadmin:
Remember to replace ‘wp_’ with your db prefix.

```
option_name
```

[image]

> wp_user_role

```
option_value
```

> a:5:{s:13:"administrator";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:13:"Administrator";s:12:"capabilities";a:61:{s:13:"switch_themes";b:1;s:11:"edit_themes";b:1;s:16:"activate_plugins";b:1;s:12:"edit_plugins";b:1;s:10:"edit_users";b:1;s:10:"edit_files";b:1;s:14:"manage_options";b:1;s:17:"moderate_comments";b:1;s:17:"manage_categories";b:1;s:12:"manage_links";b:1;s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:6:"import";b:1;s:15:"unfiltered_html";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_pages";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:8:"level_10";b:1;s:7:"level_9";b:1;s:7:"level_8";b:1;s:7:"level_7";b:1;s:7:"level_6";b:1;s:7:"level_5";b:1;s:7:"level_4";b:1;s:7:"level_3";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_pages";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_pages";b:1;s:13:"publish_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_pages";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_pages";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"read_private_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"read_private_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_users";b:1;s:12:"create_users";b:1;s:17:"unfiltered_upload";b:1;s:14:"edit_dashboard";b:1;s:14:"update_plugins";b:1;s:14:"delete_plugins";b:1;s:15:"install_plugins";b:1;s:13:"update_themes";b:1;s:14:"install_themes";b:1;s:11:"update_core";b:1;s:10:"list_users";b:1;s:12:"remove_users";b:1;s:13:"promote_users";b:1;s:18:"edit_theme_options";b:1;s:13:"delete_themes";b:1;s:6:"export";b:1;}}s:6:"editor";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Editor";s:12:"capabilities";a:34:{s:17:"moderate_comments";b:1;s:17:"manage_categories";b:1;s:12:"manage_links";b:1;s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:15:"unfiltered_html";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_pages";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_7";b:1;s:7:"level_6";b:1;s:7:"level_5";b:1;s:7:"level_4";b:1;s:7:"level_3";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_pages";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_pages";b:1;s:13:"publish_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_pages";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_pages";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_pages";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:19:"delete_others_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_posts";b:1;s:18:"read_private_posts";b:1;s:20:"delete_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"edit_private_pages";b:1;s:18:"read_private_pages";b:1;}}s:6:"author";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Author";s:12:"capabilities";a:10:{s:12:"upload_files";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:20:"edit_published_posts";b:1;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_2";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;s:22:"delete_published_posts";b:1;}}s:11:"contributor";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:11:"Contributor";s:12:"capabilities";a:5:{s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_1";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;s:12:"delete_posts";b:1;}}s:10:"subscriber";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:10:"Subscriber";s:12:"capabilities";a:2:{s:4:"read";b:1;s:7:"level_0";b:1;}}}